# React + Docker + Nginx

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx, react-router, create-react-app

I have some problem with create-react-app and docker configuration with nginx, this is my first time when i trying to dockerize react app. I tried many different settings and almost always i get 404 after build.

This is my docker file:

```
FROM node:alpine as build
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json /app/
RUN yarn install
COPY . .
RUN yarn run build

FROM nginx:alpine
COPY --from=build /app/build /usr/share/nginx.html
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Right now my nginx file looks like that, but as i said, i tried many different settings

```
server {
    listen  80;
    location / {
        root   /var/www;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
    }
}
```

[And this is what i see after build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wL0df.png)

I dont know if this is important but for routing i using react-navi.
Any ideas?

Comment: Which OS are you using? Have you checked the docker log? Have you openeed the firewall for http or 80/tcp? We need more details in order to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your Nginx configuration is looking at `/var/www` but you're copying your files to `/usr/share/nginx.html`. Shouldn't the copy command look like this?

```
COPY --from=build /app/build /var/www
```